# Change color of text when scrolling over/under another element?

Tags: css

I'm not sure what the proper terminology is for this effect. I want to say its a blend mode or clipping path thing. What I want to do is when the text get scrolled over (or under) another element to have the text change its color. See the example image below..

[image]

So the text is light gray by default then when it scrolls underneath (or over, not sure which way it should be stacked) that gray bar the text goes black.

I know I've seen this done before but just can't remember what the property used was called.

Comment: Try `text-color: rgba(-,-,-,-)`. It lets you set the opacity of the text along with its color

Comment: That's just setting the color of the text though.. I need the color to change when the text scrolls under/over that gray bar.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. the first 3 fields will set the color, the last one its opacity (0 being transparent, 1 being opaque). If you set this value, to less than 1, the text will be semi-transparent, and you will be able to see the background through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) but [`Browser Support`](http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode) still pretty bad [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/10/).

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: gray;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.box {
  width: 60%;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: #AAAAAA;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. No idea why it won't work on my site though. I even stripped it down to the basics with just a color and mix-blend-mode and its not having any effect on my text :(

Comment: On what browser you tested and did you use `difference` or some other option?

Comment: Just chrome, same browser I'm using to view your example. I have a feeling I'm running into some really weird chrome bug. I put the mix-blend-mode on another element on my site and it worked. I literally have no idea why its not working on the element I want it on. Its not something stupid like a typo in a class name because I have other styles applied to that element that are working lol.

Comment: It might be colors so you could try some other option of `mix-blend-mode:` also you could create small copy of your example in fiddle so i could take a look `:)`

Comment: Alright I got it now. Had to put the mix-blend-mode on a parent element of the one I was trying to change. I have a feeling there's a weird bug happening when javascript is making a change on that element (its part of a slider I'm using).

Comment: Nope, using Swiper (http://www.idangero.us/swiper). Just a really, really odd bug IMO. Swiper calculates a height for the element that I was trying to apply the mix-blend-mode property to. It also adds a data attribute on the element. So I think there's just some whack chrome bug happening where mix-blend-mode doesn't work if JS is applying a style or attribute to the element :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; overflow:auto;">
  <div style="height:1000px; background-color:#ccc">
    <br/><br/>EXAMPLE<br/>EXAMPLE<br/>EXAMPLE
  </div>
</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:50px; right:16px; background-color:white; opacity:0.5">
</div>
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/bexafinuti/edit?html,output

That feature can be made with css `opacity`. Content become grayed when scrolled under absolute positioned `div` with white background and half opacity

Comment: Kind of, but it needs something other than opacity. The text needs to go full black when its under that gray bar. Your example is the opposite of what I need :)

Comment: @Dustin, it is full black when not under that div with `background-color:white` and `opacity:0.5`, you can change position of that div