# Need something like mix-blend-mode to invert matching text color when intersecting bg color is the same

Tags: css, mix-blend-mode

I wonder if anyone can help me. I’ve created a Mondrian style layout using CSS Grid. I have a heading that has been rotated to be vertical that spans a couple of rows and is sticky. I’d like to achieve an effect that when a horizontal black line passes over/under the black heading text the text that intersects the line is white.

[image: Screenshot of Mondrian style grid layout]

I think I need to use mix-blend-mode. But so far I’ve not had any luck with my experiments. I’m wondering if I need to fake the horizontal line with a linear-gradient as the background to make it more image like, though I’ve failed on that count too!
I’ve added a jsfiddle below for more clarity:

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

I've checked this answer out [Change color of text when scrolling over/under another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346038/change-color-of-text-when-scrolling-over-under-another-element), but it's slightly different as it's using different colors in the blend mode.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #212121;
  background: #fdfdfd;
}

p {
  max-width: 80ch;
}

.flow > * + * {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.content {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

.content__heading {
  position: sticky;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
.content__heading h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: clamp(4.5rem, 20vmin, 7.875rem);
  line-height: 1;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: right;
  /**
   * I'm trying to get the stuck text to be white anywhere
   * the horizontal black line (grid-row: 4) crosses it.
   */
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.content__subheading {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
}

.content__section {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.block--black {
  background: #212121;
  color: #fdfdfd;
}

.block--white {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  color: #212121;
}

.block--blue {
  background: #4e9af9;
  color: #212121;
}

.block--blue-dark {
  background: #28407d;
  color: #fdfdfd;
}

.block--grey {
  background: #d4d4df;
  color: #212121;
}

.block--yellow {
  background: #e6b500;
  color: #212121;
}

.block--red {
  background: #d2241a;
  color: #212121;
}

.block--1 {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.block--2 {
  grid-column: 7;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.block--3 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.block--4 {
  grid-column: 7;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.block--5 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.block--6 {
  grid-column: 7;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.block--7 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.block--8 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 7;
}

.line {
  background: #212121;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.line--v {
  grid-row: 1/-1;
}

.line--v--1 {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.line--v--2 {
  grid-column: 4;
}

.line--v--3 {
  grid-column: 6;
}

.line--h {
  grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.line--h--1 {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.line--h--2 {
  grid-row: 4;
}

.line--h--3 {
  grid-row: 6;
}

.line--h--4 {
  grid-row: 8;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 0.625rem auto 0.625rem minmax(43.75rem, 2fr) 0.625rem 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 5rem repeat(3, 0.625rem auto);
}

.grid__heading {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3/6;
}

.grid__section {
  grid-column: 5;
}

.grid__section--1 {
  grid-row: 3;
}

.grid__section--2 {
  grid-row: 5;
}

.grid__section--3 {
  grid-row: 7;
}
```

```html
<main class="content">
    <div class="grid">
        <span class="line line--v line--v--1"></span>
        <span class="line line--v line--v--2"></span>
        <span class="line line--v line--v--3"></span>
        
        <div class="block block--grey block--1"></div>
        <div class="block block--black block--2"></div>
        
        <div class="grid__heading content__heading">
            <h2>Hello</h2>
        </div>
        <span class="line line--h line--h--1"></span>
        <section class="grid__section grid__section--1 content__section block block--blue-dark flow">
            <h3 class="content__subheading">Subheading 1</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Iure, soluta eius? Repudiandae nihil doloremque provident debitis laborum beatae laboriosam atque deserunt dicta excepturi, eius dolorem ab ducimus. Quibusdam, odio beatae.</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias maiores architecto nemo harum quia aperiam, voluptatem error et quaerat dolorum delectus a rem fuga quae sint inventore laboriosam commodi provident?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta alias eos, non deleniti necessitatibus similique at tempora animi perferendis provident sit unde accusamus fugiat totam modi nostrum? Unde, neque accusamus.</p>
        </section>
        
        <div class="block block--red block--3"></div>
        <div class="block block--yellow block--4"></div>
        <div class="block block--red block--5"></div>
        <span class="line line--h line--h--2"></span>
        <section class="grid__section grid__section--2 content__section flow">
            <h3 class="content__subheading">Subheading 2</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos et voluptate obcaecati quasi nobis aliquam, voluptates esse expedita ullam dolores quae rem itaque cupiditate nam recusandae quia ipsam praesentium omnis!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam natus asperiores delectus tenetur facere id provident nobis! Sit blanditiis debitis, recusandae assumenda laboriosam quis commodi amet, doloribus eveniet molestiae minima.</p>
        </section>
        <div class="block block--grey block--6"></div>
        
        <div class="block block--black block--7"></div>
        <div class="block block--yellow block--8"></div>
        <span class="line line--h line--h--3"></span>
        <section class="grid__section grid__section--3 content__section block--yellow flow">
            <h3 class="content__subheading">Subheading 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facere atque ad vitae nobis asperiores velit eligendi architecto, maiores reprehenderit dolore et pariatur nihil quo, provident, possimus eaque sint dolor placeat!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate natus vero quaerat expedita facere neque repellendus dolor perspiciatis ullam incidunt aliquid amet illo eligendi, totam possimus aspernatur, sequi ipsam voluptatum!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Minima ullam error sint quae! Numquam provident suscipit cum saepe quas vel delectus distinctio, magni, expedita nam sunt perferendis similique laborum eum.</p>
        </section>
        <span class="line line--h line--h--4"></span>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply mix-blend-mode to the parent element and color: white (on the text) to apply the desired effect. Keep in mind that if you're not using black (#000) or white (#fff) you might not get the colors you started out with due to blending.

My solution:

```css
.content__heading {
  position: sticky;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.content__heading h2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 1.5rem;
  font-size: clamp(4.5rem, 20vmin, 7.875rem);
  line-height: 1;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
      writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  text-align: right;
  /* add color white to achieve the right inversion */
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Slight downside with this solution is that now the text will be completely black instead of dark grey as it was originally, and the intersection will only be completely white if the line is completely black.